Java Method to check string for Capitals always returns false
I am trying to make a simple password checker program in Java that checks a bunch of things about the user's password before allowing them to continue.
One of the thngs it checks for is making sure there is at least one capital letter in the passcode. Here is the code, first, the method that is used:
 public static boolean checkString(String str) {
    char ch;
    boolean capitalFlag = false;
   
    for(int i=0;i < str.length();i++) {
        
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        
        capitalFlag = Character.isUpperCase(ch);
    }   
    return capitalFlag;
}

Then, the else if statement that checks this:
else if (!checkString(enterPasswordAgain) || !checkString(enterPasswordAgain)){
            btnSubmit.setForeground(Color.RED);
            btnSubmit.setText("Make sure your password has at least one capital letter.");  
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        else {
            btnSubmit.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            btnSubmit.setText("Excellent password!");  
            System.out.println("true");
        }

This returns false every time for some reason, despite the fact that this is the final thing checked and shouldn't cause any issues. I am very new to Java, could someone explain why this is not working? Thank you!
Tldr: Returns false every time despite being supposed to return whatever the value of capitalFlag is

In your code, every iteration, you get the character then set the flag. The result is that after the last iteration, the value in the variable is just whatever was set on the last iteration - i.e. the last character. Every iteration overwrites the previous one. Your code will return true if the last character is uppercase.

"This returns false every time for some reason" - not quite; it'll return true for "last letter is capitaL" for example...

Yeah, that makes sense now, thank you for the help! I didn't realize the flaw in that the capitalFlag will only ever check the final character by the time the value is returned from the method.

The problem is that you are only returning the status of the last character.  Try it like this.
public static boolean checkString(String str) {

    for(char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;   
}

You may want to rename this method to containsUpperCase()

Thank you very much! This makes sense, I didn't realize that obviously the variable would only display the value of the final character in the sequence. Works perfectly, only thing was I had to add the char ch; declaration again as well as the line telling it to get the char at i. Otherwise, worked perfectly, thanks so much!

@WilliamHughes  Glad to help.  BTW, I didn't use the chatAt(i) method as I iterate over the character array provided by the String class.  But your way is perfectly acceptable.

Here's an alternative, much shorter way: return str.chars().anyMatch(Character::isUpperCase)

Even better is to use code point integer numbers rather than outmoded char type: str.codePoints().anyMatch( Character :: isUppercase )

@BasilBourque  You've made this observation quite a few times.  Why do you think that the maintainers of the API have not thought to deprecate the char based methods?

@WJS Probably for the same reason the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes were briefly marked for deprecation, then mysteriously undone.
